# How to create component library in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-sfc

### Motivation

Create vuejs library with components (buttons, headers,...) for re-using it in more projects so they looks the same in different projects.

### My not working idea

I would like to reach something like this:

When you have these files

- `/src/components/TestComponent.vue` - vue SFC
- `/src/main.js`
- `/src/package.js`

Where:

- `TestComponent.vue`:

```js
    <template>
      <div class="test-component">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'test-component',
      props: {
        msg: String
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

- `/src/main.js` export that component:

```js
import testComponent from './components/TestComponent.vue'

export { testComponent }
```

- `packake.json` contains build description which should create library:

```json
{   
    "name": "@my/test-lib",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name test-lib src/main.js",
...
```

So I can build it via `npm run build` and afterwards `npm publish` to private repo and afterwards use component `TestComponent` in another project like this:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <test-component msg="TEST"></test-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { testComponent } from "@my/test-lib"

export default {
    name: "usage-test",
    components: {
        testComponent
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

---> **Except it doesnt work**. It fails on `Cannot find module '@my/test-lib'`. My guess is that I am doing export somehow wrong. *Can someone provide a hint?*

### Working idea

- `TestComponent.vue` looks exactly the same as above
- `main.js` use `@vue/web-component-wrapper`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import wrap from "@vue/web-component-wrapper";

import testComponent from "./components/TestComponent.vue";
const wrappedTestComponent = wrap(Vue, testComponent);
window.customElements.define("test-component", wrappedTestComponent);
```

But this solution has a limitation. When usage - it accepts only `String` props. So no Objects by nature (I am not counting ser / deser brittle solution)

Comment: what does "ser / deser" mean?

Comment: serialization / deserialization via `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. So usage is via object serialized into string and afterwards compoent has to deserialize that string back into object.